# Spectrum and sentences

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is there an example of a language with only one spectrum equal to the even numbers?

Also, is there an example of a language with only relation which has spectrum equal to the set of non-primes?

A spectrum I understand is the set S of all natural numbers n s.t. there is a model of phi with exactly n elements.

Comment: In both questions are you asking for a theory in a language whose only non-logical symbol is a relation?

Comment: Yes, relation in terms of a language

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are. The positive answers follow from the well-known result that a set of natural numbers is a spectrum if and only if it is in NP and recognizable in time $2^{O(n)}$. See http://www.jstor.org/stable/2272354; the result is stated on the first page which should be visible even without a subscription.